# replace ntext (more than 4000 characters) in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, replace, ntext

How to replace text in sql server 2000 in a ntext column with more than 4000 characters? conversion to nvarchar(max) does not work as it truncates values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with TEXT/NTEXT is a mess - one of the many reason to get rid of those fields as quickly as possible.

You need to manipulate those with command such as READTEXT, WRITETEXT, UPDATETEXT and other - see some resources for help:

- [MSDN docs on READTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238511%28SQL.80%29.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on WRITETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260673%28SQL.80%29.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on UPDATETEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260658%28SQL.80%29.aspx)
- [How do I handle REPLACE() within an NTEXT column in SQL Server?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150521050102/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-handle-replace-within-an-ntext-column-in-sql-server.html)
- [Update Text, NText Columns using UPDATETEXT Command in MS SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/update-text-column-using-updatetext.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

nvarchar(max) isn't supported until sql server 2005.  For sql server 2000 columns with more than 4000 wide characters, you must pull the data down to a client application and make your changes there.