# alternatives to REPLACE on a text or ntext datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update/replace the data in datatable.column. The table has a field named `Content`. I'm using the `REPLACE` function. Since the column datatype is `NTEXT`, SQL Server doesn't allow me to use the `REPLACE` function.

I can't change the datatype because this database is 3rd party software table. Changing the datatype will cause the application to fail.

```
UPDATE [CMS_DB_test].[dbo].[cms_HtmlText] 
SET Content = REPLACE(Content,'ABC','DEF') 
WHERE Content LIKE '%ABC%'
```

I Receive this error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

- Can I fix this with T-SQL? Does someone have an example how to read and to loop?
- Since this is onetime conversion, maybe I can change to another type but I'm afraid I'm messing up the data.

There is a primary key field: name: ID  - integer - it's an identity.... So I need to think about this too. Maybe set the Identity to N temporary.

Please advise on how to achieve the REPLACE function?

Approx. 3000 statements need to be updated with a new solution.

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2000?

Comment: ANSWER: I'm using SQL2008... and the DATABASE has Compatibility level 2000 (80). If I change this too 2008 will it then work? since I do not know the consequences yet I left at compatibility level 2000, but it's SQL 2008 Database.

this is one time conversion...

Answer (score 220, accepted):

**IF** your data won't overflow 4000 characters **AND** you're on SQL Server 2000 or compatibility level of 8 or SQL Server 2000:

```
UPDATE [CMS_DB_test].[dbo].[cms_HtmlText] 
SET Content = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Content as NVarchar(4000)),'ABC','DEF') AS NText)
WHERE Content LIKE '%ABC%'
```

For SQL Server 2005+:

```
UPDATE [CMS_DB_test].[dbo].[cms_HtmlText] 
SET Content = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Content as NVarchar(MAX)),'ABC','DEF') AS NText)
WHERE Content LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Comment: Just a quick question, is the second cast to `NText` really necessary?  I would think that assigning `NVarchar(MAX)` to `NText` would automatically cast it.

Comment: Great simple fix. Just a note that the 2005+ nvarchar(max) doesn't have 4000 char limit. I know it's obvious (now, to me), but I first read it as if both answers had that limit.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming SQL Server 2000, the following [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133635/replace-ntext-more-than-4000-characters-in-sql-server-2000) should address your problem.

If using SQL Server 2005/2008, you can use the following code (taken from [here](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2008/02/27/how-to-use-replace-within-ntext-columns-in-sql-server/)):

```
select cast(replace(cast(myntext as nvarchar(max)),'find','replace') as ntext)
from myntexttable
```