# "update" sql for remove same string from all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My website attacked and hackers adds **same** string to all of my rows.
For example if the value of a row was `"True value"` they changed it to `"True Value HACKED STRING ... HACKED  by .. "`

Unfortunately my site have lots of data and I can't change them one by one, but fortunately same data adds to all rows.
I want an SQL statement that removes all `HACKED STRING` from all rows.

Comment: is the added string same all over the rows?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that quickly by removing the string with `REPLACE` function

Example TableA

```
  id | Name
 --------------
  1  | Good HACKED BY XX
  2  | We know HACKED BY XX
  3  | Goodbye HACKED BY XX
```

Sql

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, ' HACKED BY XX', '');
```

This will make you table look like this

```
  id | Name
 --------------
  1  | Good
  2  | We know
  3  | Goodbye
```

Comment: this error occurred :   Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: @MHF this might be because of the lenght, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype