# UPDATE and REPLACE part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, replace

I've got a table with two columns, `ID` and `Value`. I want to change a part of some strings in the second column.

Example of Table:

```
ID            Value
---------------------------------
1             c:\temp\123\abc\111
2             c:\temp\123\abc\222
3             c:\temp\123\abc\333
4             c:\temp\123\abc\444
```

Now the `123\` in the `Value` string is not needed. I tried `UPDATE` and `REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, '%123%', '')
WHERE ID <= 4
```

When I execute the script SQL Server does not report an error, but it does not update anything either. Why is that?

Comment: It does not replace anything because the wildcards are not treated as wildcards but rather as literals.

Answer (score 974, accepted):

You don't need wildcards in the `REPLACE` - it just finds the string you enter for the second argument, so the following should work:

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, '123', '')
WHERE ID <=4
```

If the column to replace is type `text` or `ntext` you need to cast it to nvarchar

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(CAST(Value as nVarchar(4000)), '123', '')
WHERE ID <=4
```

Comment: It work grate, but not with ntext type :( ...>> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 - Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: I just found the solution :) ===> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype

Comment: Wait, what is with the `\`? isn't that escaping the `'` character and making this incorrect?

Comment: This was helpful

Comment: This will not work if your Column type is Text or NText, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype

Answer (score 79):

Try to remove `%` chars as below

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, '123', '')
WHERE ID <=4
```

Answer (score 68):

To make the query run **faster** in big tables where not every line needs to be updated, you can also choose to only update rows that will be modified:

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx
SET Value = REPLACE(Value, '123', '')
WHERE ID <= 4
AND Value LIKE '%123%'
```

Answer (score 60):

query:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET field_name = REPLACE(field_name , 'oldstring', 'newstring') 
WHERE field_name LIKE ('oldstring%');
```

Answer (score 10):

You have one table where you have date Code which is seven character something like

```
"32-1000"
```

Now you want to replace all

```
"32-"
```

With

```
"14-"
```

The SQL query you have to run is

```
Update Products Set Code = replace(Code, '32-', '14-') Where ...(Put your where statement in here)
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone want to replace your script.

`update dbo.[TABLE_NAME] set COLUMN_NAME= replace(COLUMN_NAME, 'old_value', 'new_value') where COLUMN_NAME like %CONDITION%`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT this is why reddit has the mad memes about SO

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_PersonalDetail
(ID INT IDENTITY ,[Date] nvarchar(20), Name nvarchar(20), GenderID int);

INSERT INTO Tbl_PersonalDetail VALUES(N'18-4-2015', N'Monay', 2),
                                     (N'31-3-2015', N'Monay', 2),
                                     (N'28-12-2015', N'Monay', 2),
                                     (N'19-4-2015', N'Monay', 2)

DECLARE @Date Nvarchar(200)

SET @Date = (SELECT [Date] FROM Tbl_PersonalDetail WHERE ID = 2)

Update Tbl_PersonalDetail SET [Date] = (REPLACE(@Date , '-','/')) WHERE ID = 2
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

you should use  the below update query

```
UPDATE dbo.xxx SET Value=REPLACE(Value,'123\','') WHERE Id IN(1, 2, 3, 4)

UPDATE dbo.xxx SET Value=REPLACE(Value,'123\','') WHERE Id <= 4
```

Either of the above queries should work.

Answer (score 0):

replace for persian word

```
UPDATE dbo.TblNews
SET keyWords = REPLACE(keyWords, '-', N'،')
```

help:
dbo.TblNews -- table name

keyWords   -- fild name