# Replace a URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to replace all URLs href attribute in all my Wordpress posts body/content (over 1 million) to my new domain "Contact Us" URL like:

```
http://old-domain.com/any-page
http://old-domain.com/any-page-2
http://old-domain.com/any-page-3
http://old-domain.com/any-page-4
```

to like

```
http://new-domain.com/contact
```

Can I do this using php? Or is there any plugin for it?

I can not redirect my old domain to new domain because it is expired and I do not have access to it. I have to change URL's href attribute in every Wordpress post.

Comment: I would run a SQL to [find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365278/541591) and then write an HTTP redirection rule, if you are using Apache then with [rewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945599/541591). Unfortunately we can't help you write codes, I suggest you experiment with the links I shared and report back with your findings.

Comment: Have you migrated your wordpress website to any other domain? if yes, then you might just need to go into your `Settings`, and go into `Permalinks` (where you change your URL format. And just hit SAVE. If it is something else then you might need to run `mysql` replace() in your DB.

Comment: There are some plugins that can help you, for example: Velvet Blues Updates URL, WP Migrate DB or Search and Replace Plugin.

Comment: do you have database access for the old-domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this great tool [Search and Replace](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB), it works like a charm, the process is as below.

- Download the [script from github](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB).
- Upload it into the root of your host that you can open it easily.
- Open the URL in the browser, for example, **www.yourdomain.com/Search-Replace-DB**.
- Database connection will be done automatically no need for any authentications.
- At the top of the page there is two text fields (**replace** and **with**) add your old URL (http://old-domain.com) without forward slash at the end (/) in the **replace** and add the new URL(http://new-domain.com) without forward slash at the end (/) into the **with** field.
- Press **live run** and wait until it's done.
- Once you are done make sure you remove the Search and Replace folder (Security Reason)