# How to do a find and replace special character in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find and replace numerous "special characters" in my database that was entered in from a different charset.

I have looked around and found the `REPLACE` function in SQL Server and have tried the following:

```
UPDATE mans_brands_packages
SET package_content = REPLACE(package_content, 'œ', '&')
WHERE package_content LIKE '%œ%'
```

But I get a error as such:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

It is because SQL Server doesn't take "œ" as an argument? Thanks.

Comment: Remove that `WHERE` part from your `update` statement.

Comment: `package_content` is of TEXT type, which is invalid for REPLACE function. You can try alternatives like http://stackoverflow.com/a/4341677/961695

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, `package_content LIKE '%œ%'` anyways won't make much sense since `REPLACE` will replace the character upon finding it; else nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to `replace` against a `text` field - [`replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) expects a `(n)(var)char` data type as the first parameter.

```
UPDATE mans_brands_packages
SET package_content = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),package_content),'œ','&')
WHERE package_content LIKE '%œ%'
```

Also, the `text` data type is deprecated. You should change it to an `(n)varchar(max)` field