# SQL: Alternative to text and ntext data type?

Tags: sql, text, char, varchar, ntext

I'm currently designing a MS SQL table for use in a project. The problem I'm currently facing is that the [data types of "Transact SQL "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187752.aspx) are pointing to the deprecation of the types "text" and "ntext", which I always used for big texts.

Char, nchar, varchar and nvarchar may only be 8000 bytes big, this just isn't enough for a user input text, e. g. if he's writing a big article.

Is there any alternative to the obsolete data type text/ntext?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `nvarchar(MAX)`  will allow you to store up to 2 GB of data. The same goes for `varchar(MAX)` too.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because of the "8000" Bytes maximum.

Answer (score 0):

varchar(MAX) and nvarchar(MAX).  Try 'em; you'll like 'em.

Answer (score 0):

*If you're using SQL **2005+***, you could use `n / varchar(max)` instead.  `nvarchar` will use `unicode`, and `varchar` will use `ascii`.  If this is used to store blog text, then I would go with `nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 0):

If you finished reading the paragraph on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187993.aspx) page you linked, which explained that they were being removed, you would have found your answer:

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. **Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead**.