# SQL Server - Insert Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am trying to select the contents of another row and insert it into the table but changing particular values. Inside this I am trying to use a `Replace()` function to replace certain characters in the given column.

Is this correct or will I need to take this out and do this via an `Update` statement?

This is my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PurchaseLogic]
       ([column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,[column3]
       ,[column4])
SELECT  [column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,replace(column3, 'TextA','TextB')
       ,[column4]
FROM dbo.purchaselogic 
WHERE column1 = 1
```

hanks

EDIT

Sorry, this is the error I am getting when executing it:

> Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: It looks correct. Are you having any issues?

Comment: this will work because your replace is called in your select statement.

Comment: where is the error ?????what you want first of all???

Comment: Do you want to replace a value in the database or just on the returning values?

Comment: Updated question with message received when executed

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) (seems your `column3` is of type `text` - change it to `varchar(max)` to be able to use all the usual string functions!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks correct to me and should do what you are wanting to do. But is there some reason why you simply can't try this yourself and check the results?

If Column3 is a data type of 'Text', this isn't going to work since Replace doesn't work on that data type. You could cast the data type is nvarchar(max) to make this work. For example:

```
Replace(Cast(column3 as varchar(max)),'TextA','TextB')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PurchaseLogic]
       ([column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,[column3]
       ,[column4])
SELECT  [column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,CAST(REPLACE(CAST(column3 as Varchar(MAX)),'TextA','TextB') AS Text)
       ,[column4]
FROM dbo.purchaselogic 
WHERE column1 = 1
```

I got the essense of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype)

Answer (score 1):

column3 is a `TEXT` column, you need to cast it as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` to use the `REPLACE` function:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PurchaseLogic]
       ([column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,[column3]
       ,[column4])
SELECT  [column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,REPLACE(CAST(column3 AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 'TextA','TextB')
       ,[column4]
FROM dbo.purchaselogic 
WHERE column1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PurchaseLogic]
       ([column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,[column3]
       ,[column4])
SELECT  [column1]
       ,[column2]
       ,cast(replace(cast(column3 as nvarchar(max)),'TextA','TextB') as ntext)
       ,[column4]
FROM dbo.purchaselogic 
WHERE column1 = 1
```

Comment: If `column3` is `TEXT`, you shouldn't be converting that to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (but rather use `varchar(max)`)

Comment: yes you are right @marc_s..we don't know the exact data..anyway point noted down...

Comment: We **know** the exact data type - the error message **clearly says** it's of type `text` (non-Unicode)  ....

Answer (score 0):

The various solutions presented above should make the query work but if you're going to be doing this kind of thing on a regular basis you should at least consider fixing the problem at source and changing the datatype of [dbo].[PurchaseLogic].[column3] to VARCHAR(MAX)

You can do this with an ALTER TABLE command bit I'd probably do it by creating a new table and inserting the data into it

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseLogic_new]
 (
 [column1] int,
 [column2] int,
 [column3] varchar(max),
 [column4] int
 )    
 INSERT INTO dbo.PurchaseLogic_new ([column1],[column2],[column3],[column4] )
 SELECT [column1],[column2],[column3],[column4]  FROM [dbo].[PurchaseLogic]
```

Once that's done you can swap the names round

```
 EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.PurchaseLogic','PurchaseLogic_old','OBJECT'
 EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.PurchaseLogic_new','PurchaseLogic','OBJECT'
```

You can then back out the change by swapping the names back

```
 EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.PurchaseLogic','PurchaseLogic_new','OBJECT'
 EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.PurchaseLogic_old','PurchaseLogic','OBJECT'
```