# SQL Server query to delete text from text column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have a SQL Server database with a table `feedback` that contains a text column `comment`. In that column I have tag data, for example

```
This is my record <tag>Random characters are here</tag> with information.
```

How do I write a query to update all of these records to remove the `<tag></tag>` and all of the text in between?

I'd like to write this to a different 'temporary' table to first verify the changes and then update the original table.

I am running SQL Server 2014 Express.

Thank you

Comment: T-SQL is the wrong tool for this.  Try writing a little console app that reads these field values and parses them using RegEx or an HTML parser like HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Do 2 Substrings using as refernce the opening and closing tags and concat them together in an update

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype), I think it will help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to remove tags..

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveTag](@text NVARCHAR(MAX), @tag as nvarchar(max))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @startTagIndex as int
    declare @endTagIndex as int

    set @startTagIndex = CHARINDEX('<' + @tag + '>', @text)
    if(@startTagIndex > 0) BEGIN
        set @endTagIndex = CHARINDEX('</' + @tag + '>', @text, @startTagIndex)
        if(@endTagIndex > 0) BEGIN
            return LEFT(@text, @startTagIndex - 1) + RIGHT(@text, len(@text) - len(@tag) - @endTagIndex  - 2)
        END
    END

    return @text
END
```

Later you can use it like:

```
Update table set field = dbo.RemoveTag(field, 'tag')
```

If you want to write fields to other table then:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OtherTable (
    OtherField nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO OtherTable (OtherField)
SELECT dbo.RemoveTag(field, 'tag') from table
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a lot assumptions about the format of your string. But if they're valid then this is very simple:

```
left(s, charindex('<tag>', s - 1)) +
    substring(s, charindex('</tag>', s) + 6, len(s))
```

Obviously we're basically assuming that the search strings appear only once and in the correct order. There's also an assumption that there will be matches. Also, I used `len(s)` as an easy upper bound on the number of characters to take from the right. You could just hard-code something appropriate if you felt like it since SQL Server doesn't error for going past the end. `s` is just a stand in for your char column.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/771a3/8

Not sure if extra whitespace is going to be an issue so you might want to trim and add a space character in the middle.

```
rtrim(left(s, charindex('<tag>', s) - 1)) + ' ' +
    ltrim(substring(s, charindex('</tag>', s) + 6, len(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX to find where your tags start and stop, SUBSTRING to get all text between < and >, and REPLACE to swap out the substring for ''.

```
Select Field, 
Substring(FIELD, charindex('<', Field), CHARINDEX('>', Field, 
    (CHARINDEX('>', FIELD)) + 1) - charindex('<', Field)+1)  as ToRemove,
replace (Field, Substring(FIELD, charindex('<', Field), CHARINDEX('>',
    Field, (CHARINDEX('>', FIELD)) + 1) - charindex('<', Field)+1), '') 
    as FinalResult
```

from TableName

The output will be three columns, Field, ToRemove and FinalResult, but nothing will actually be updated.

I think the only way this will fail is if you have nested tags.  `<b><i>sometext</i></b>`

To actually make the change:

```
Update #TableName set Field = replace (Field, Substring(FIELD, charindex('<', Field), CHARINDEX('>', Field, (CHARINDEX('>', FIELD)) + 1) - charindex('<', Field)+1), '')
```

Tested on SQL Server 2012.