# REPLACE function for SQL server is not changing the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

The column is of datatype `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

I want to add a string to my value

```
UPDATE Winner
SET [Text] = CAST(REPLACE(CAST([Text] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'xxx You won ticket xxx', 'xxx You won semi final ticket xxx') AS NTEXT)
WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxx'
```

This doesn't work.

Nothing is changing after the update - the value is unchanged.

How can I replace my text ?

Comment: `'%You won ticket%'` doesn't need the percentage characters

Comment: Are you trying to use `%` as a wildcard? `REPLACE` doesn't use wildcards; they are used for pattern matching (i.e. with a `LIKE` operator if the `PATINDEX` function). If they are meant to be wildcards, what *are* you trying to achieve here? Sample data and expected results would greatly help.

Comment: If the column is `NVarchar(MAX)` as stated why are you converting to `NVarchar(MAX)` then back to `NTEXT`? Just leave it as is

Comment: i edited my question. i was trying with wildcards. i changed back to original.

Comment: *"Nothing is changing after the update. my value stays same."* then the **literal** string `'xxx You won ticket xxx'` doesn't appear in your column `[Text]`.

Comment: @martin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341613/alternatives-to-replace-on-a-text-or-ntext-datatype

Comment: So that would indicate that the column is `ntext` - not `nvarchar max` as you state in the very first line of the Q

Comment: in my data there is a date part. i dont want to change it.

Comment: If you are using `text`, why are you? It's been deprecated for 14+ years.

Comment: Are you saying that there is variable text that needs to be retained inside the substring that you are replacing? If so that isn't clear from your example. It looks like you can just blanket replace `You won ticket` with `You won semi final ticket`

Comment: @MartinSmith it doesn't work like that. I don't know why.

Comment: because you included unneeded percentages in the original code you posted

Comment: I tried without percentages firstly. Later i tried with them and still wasn't working.So I   wanted to ask quesiton. I tried without CAST too. but anyway question is resolved. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STUFF()` :

```
DECLARE @UpdateText VARCHAR(255) = 'xxx You won ticket xxx' -- whatever data type you have
DECLARE @NewText VARCHAR(255) = 'xxx You won semi final ticket xxx' -- whatever data type you have

UPDATE Winner
     SET [Text] = STUFF([Text], PATINDEX('%' + @UpdateText + '%', [Text]), LEN(@UpdateText), @NewText)
WHERE Id = 'xxxxxxx'
```

Comment: that worked sir !